# Is it possible to merge 2 webspaces in PLESK 12?

Tags: plesk

There are 2 Webspaces on my PLESK Server which I can access as a Poweruser. Is it possible to merge them or at least to transfer files without FTP. The package I want to transfer is about 27 gb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it automatically. 
You need to use ssh client and mv command

Common SSH Commands - 
[Command link](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/247/Common+SSH+Commands#gs)